# Wrong signature error using function types in multiple modules

Tags: python, function, module, cython

I have the following Cython modules:

```
compmech    
    integrate
        integratev.pxd
        integratev.pyx
    conecyl
        main.pyx
```

In `integratev.pxd` I've declared:

```
ctypedef void (*f_type)(int npts, double *xs, double *ts, double *out,
                    double *alphas, double *betas, void *args) nogil

cdef int trapz2d(f_type f, int fdim, np.ndarray[cDOUBLE, ndim=1] final_out,
                 double xmin, double xmax, int m,
                 double ymin, double ymax, int n,
                 void *args, int num_cores)
```

I call `trapz2d` from `main.pyx`, and the function passed to `trapz2d` is declared in `main.pyx`, e.g:

```
from compmech.integrate.integratev cimport trapz2d

cdef void cfk0L(int npts, double *xs, double *ts, double *out,
                double *alphas, double *betas, void *args) nogil:
    ...

trapz2d(<f_type>cfk0L, fdim, k0Lv, xa, xb, nx, ta, tb, nt, &args, num_cores)
```

It compiles just fine, but when I run I get the error:

```
TypeError: C function compmech.integrate.integratev.trapz2d has wrong signature       
(expected int (__pyx_t_8compmech_9integrate_10integratev_f_type, int, PyArrayObject *,
               double, double, int, double, double, int, void *, int),
 got int (__pyx_t_10integratev_f_type, int, PyArrayObject *,
          double, double, int, double, double, int, void *, int))
```

It seems like a bug to me, but perhaps I am missing something important here...

---

Note: it works when I put everything inside `main.pyx` instead of using multiple modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does indeed seem like a bug where the automatic attempt to merge the types in `filename.pxd` and `filename.pyx` fails. Using `void*` is one workaround, but if you want to avoid casting, you can create a third file `_util.pxd` that contains the shared definition of the function pointer.

```
# _util.pxd

ctypedef void (*f_type)(int npts, double *xs, double *ts, double *out,
                        double *alphas, double *betas, void *args) nogil
```

And then you can import the shared typedef into both `integrate.pxd` and `integrate.pyx` which guarantees that the types are the same.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to pass everything as `void *` and just cast to `<f_type>` before the function is actually executed, inside `trapz2d()`. The final layout of the code is:

```
ctypedef void (*f_type)(int npts, double *xs, double *ts, double *out,
                    double *alphas, double *betas, void *args) nogil

cdef int trapz2d(void *fin, int fdim, np.ndarray[cDOUBLE, ndim=1] final_out,
                 double xmin, double xmax, int m,
                 double ymin, double ymax, int n,
                 void *args, int num_cores)
    cdef f_type f
    f = <f_type>fin
    ...
```

and in the other code:

```
from compmech.integrate.integratev cimport trapz2d

cdef void cfk0L(int npts, double *xs, double *ts, double *out,
                double *alphas, double *betas, void *args) nogil:
    ...

trapz2d(<void *>cfk0L, fdim, k0Lv, xa, xb, nx, ta, tb, nt, &args, num_cores)
```