# Cython error on import: C function has wrong signature

Tags: python, typeerror, cython

As part of larger cython project I am getting an error that seems to indicate that maybe the automatic type merging is failing. It is possible I am doing something silly or that the fact that I am structuring things in this way is a bad smell. I think I can get around the issue by using void* and then casts everywhere but this seems quite messy for what should be a simple thing.

It seems similar to this issue, but that involved function pointers.

[Wrong signature error using function types in multiple modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845057/wrong-signature-error-using-function-types-in-multiple-modules)

I have put together a minimal example that demonstrates the issue. The files are as follows.

a.pxd

```
cdef struct A:
    int a


cdef A makeA(int a)
```

a.pyx

```
cdef struct A:
    pass

cdef A makeA(int a):
    cdef A sA
    sA.a = a
    return sA
```

b.pyx

```
from cfr.a cimport A, makeA


cdef int get_A_value():
    cdef A sA = makeA(5)
    return sA.a
```

If I compile and then try to import b in a jupyter-lab notebook I get the following error:

```
b.pyx in init b()

TypeError: C function cfr.a.makeA has wrong signature (expected struct __pyx_t_3cfr_1a_A (int), got struct __pyx_t_1a_A (int))
```

EDIT: It looks like it might be something to do with my directory structure. Note that I do from cfr.a cimport A (as this happens to be the layout of my project). I think I need to do from a import A and get the import to work through the use of my pythonpath.

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that it's because you're redeclaring struct A in a.pyx. I think that's only necessary for cdef classes (where you provide the implementation in the pyx file) and not for structs

Comment: Thanks. I tried removing that cdef struct A pass section previously and just double checked it now. I still get the same error.

Comment: Interestingly I also tried moving the definition of struct A into its own file. This actually did produce an error at compile time which looked fairly similar. b.c:1101:14: error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'struct __pyx_t_3cfr_1c_A' from type 'struct __pyx_t_1c_A'
   __pyx_v_sA = __pyx_f_3cfr_1a_makeA(5);

Comment: The other thing that works (now I've had a chance to have a proper look) is adding an `__init__.pxd` file to the cfr directory. It's fine to answer your own question but please post it as an answer rather than an edit to the question!

Comment: Thanks again. Adding a blank `__init__.pxd` didn't work for me. I'll move it into an answer tomorrow. I didn't know if answering your own Q was the done thing.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out the issue was in the from cfr.a cimport A line. This was somehow meaning that the A type was not being seen as the same type as A in the a.pyx file.

To fix use:
from a cimport A

(You may then get a not found error, but we can fix this with our pythonpath).

In the comments adding a  `__init__.pxd` file was suggested, but adding a blank one did not work for me.